# SQL Server : max date and inner join

Tags: sql, database, windows, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables, one is a list of tasks. The other containing historical values for those tasks.

I need to generate a list of the latest event (and its description) for each check, as long as long as its `Date_Executed` is less than the current datetime minus the `Timeframe` (`TimeFrame` being hours within the task has to be done, formatted for use in `DATEADD`). But only if they have an `active = 1`.

Table: **checks**

```
Check_id  description  TimeFrame active
1         Task One     -24       0
2         Task Two     -24       0
3         Task Forty   -48       1
4         Task Somehin -128      1
```

Table: **events**

```
Event_id  Check_id   Comment     Date_Executed             User_Executed
1         1          NULL        2012-09-18 16:10:44.917   admin
2         1          NULL        2012-09-25 11:39:01.000   jeff
3         4          Failed      2012-09-25 13:20:09.930   steve
4         4          Half failed 2012-09-25 13:05:09.953   marsha
5         2          NULL        2012-09-25 14:02:24.000   marsha
6         3          NULL        2012-09-18 16:10:55.023   marsha
```

The best solutions I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Date_Executed]
    a.[Check_id], 
    a.[Comments],
    b.[frequency], 
    b.[Check_id],
    b.[description]     
FROM 
    [checksdb].[dbo].events as a, 
    [checksdb].[dbo].checks as b
where 
    b.active = 1
    and a.[Date_Executed] < = dateadd(HOUR,b.[frequency],GETDATE())
    and a.Check_id = b.Check_id
order by Check_id, priority
```

and

```
select MAX(date_Executed), Task_id from daily_check_events group by Task_id
```

Neither of which gets me what I need, I could really use some help.

Comment: In addition to the queries you've tried that don't give you the results you want, could you show the results you want? Also, [please stop using `FROM table_a, table_b` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are `SQL Server` which supports `Common Table Expression` and `Window Function`. Try this,

```
WITH latestEvents
AS
(
  SELECT  Event_id, Check_id, [Comment], Date_Executed, User_Executed,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Check_ID ORDER BY DATE_Executed DESC) 
              AS RowNum
  FROM    events
)
SELECT  a.[Check_id], a.[description],
        b.[Date_Executed], b.[Comment]
FROM    checks a
        INNER JOIN latestEvents b
            on a.check_ID = b.check_ID
WHERE   b.RowNum = 1 AND
        a.active = 1
        -- other conditions here
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35cc8/8)

The above query will only work on RDBMS that supports `Window Functions`. Alternatively, use the query below that works on most RDBMS

```
SELECT  a.Check_id, a.description,
        c.Date_Executed, c.Comment
FROM    checks a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT check_id, MAX(Date_Executed) maxExecuted
          FROM   events
          GROUP BY check_ID
        ) b ON a.check_ID = b.check_ID
        INNER JOIN events c
          ON c.check_ID = b.check_ID AND
             c.date_executed = b.maxExecuted
WHERE   a.active = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35cc8/13)

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up using the `Common Table Expression` Version". ( Sorry about late reply, had to exhaustively test.)